# What is the difference between Revoke, Terminate and Kill when using djcelery?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, celery, djcelery

I am using djcelery and django's admin site. If I want to stop a djcelery task that has started, do I use revoke, terminate or kill and what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `terminate` to kill an already started task.

**revoke:**

```
>>> from celery.task.control import revoke
>>> revoke(task_id)
```

When a worker receives a revoke request it will skip executing the task, but it won’t terminate an already executing task.

**terminate:**

```
>>> from celery.task.control import revoke
>>> revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

If terminate is set the worker child process processing the task will be terminated. The default signal sent is TERM. Terminating a task also revokes it.

**kill:**

This is different from the above two. `KILL` is used to kill workers

```
ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```